# Failure on Pandas Installation Using PyPy interpreter on PyCharm

Tags: python, pandas, pip, pypy

I've been trying to install pandas using the PyPy interpreter on Pycharm on a windows machine. I've troubleshooted the issues online extensively and can't resolve it. I've used the built in Pycharm module installer and also the CMD window. I've tried with and without the no-cache-dir command. I've installed microsoft Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019. I've checked that pip is the latest version. I can install other modules but for some reason pandas won't install. Numpy also fails on installation. Here is the error I get; any help would be appreciated.

```
        (PYPYVE~1) C:\Users\flegg>pip install pandas
```

```
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b7/93/b544dd08092b457d88e10fc1e0989d9397fd32ca936fdfcbb2584
178dd2b/pandas-0.25.3.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\flegg\pypy venv\bin\pypy.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\
\Users\\flegg\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kv0nhuc2\\pandas\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\flegg\\
AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kv0nhuc2\\pandas\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file
__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' e
gg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\flegg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kv0nhuc2\pandas\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\flegg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kv0nhuc2\pandas\
    Complete output (216 lines):
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: 'c:\users\flegg\pypy venv\bin\pypy.exe' 'c:\users\flegg\pypy venv\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep5
17\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\flegg\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_z50eost'
             cwd: C:\Users\flegg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-ydesvn0r\numpy
        Complete output (180 lines):
        Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
        Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
        Processing numpy/random\_bit_generator.pyx
        Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pyx.in
        Processing numpy/random\_common.pyx
        Processing numpy/random\_generator.pyx
        Processing numpy/random\_mt19937.pyx
        Processing numpy/random\_pcg64.pyx
        Processing numpy/random\_philox.pyx
        Processing numpy/random\_sfc64.pyx
        Cythonizing sources
        blas_opt_info:
        blas_mkl_info:
        customize MSVCCompiler
          libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        blis_info:
          libraries blis not found in ['C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        openblas_info:
          libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\']
        get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95',
'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
        customize GnuFCompiler
        Could not locate executable g77
        Could not locate executable f77
        customize IntelVisualFCompiler
        Could not locate executable ifort
        Could not locate executable ifl
        customize AbsoftFCompiler
        Could not locate executable f90
        customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
        Could not locate executable DF
        customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
        Could not locate executable efl
        customize Gnu95FCompiler
        Could not locate executable gfortran
        Could not locate executable f95
        customize G95FCompiler
        Could not locate executable g95
        customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
        customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
        Could not locate executable efort
        Could not locate executable efc
        customize PGroupFlangCompiler
        Could not locate executable flang
        don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
          libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_3_10_blas_info:
          libraries satlas not found in ['C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_blas_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_blas_info:
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        accelerate_info:
          NOT AVAILABLE

        blas_info:
          libraries blas not found in ['C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        blas_src_info:
          NOT AVAILABLE

          NOT AVAILABLE

        'svnversion' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
        operable program or batch file.
        non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
        lapack_opt_info:
        lapack_mkl_info:
          libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        openblas_lapack_info:
          libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        openblas_clapack_info:
          libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        flame_info:
          libraries flame not found in ['C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_3_10_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
          libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_3_10_info:
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
          libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_threads_info:
        Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
          libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE

        atlas_info:
          libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
          libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
        <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
          NOT AVAILABLE

        lapack_info:
          libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\']
          NOT AVAILABLE

        lapack_src_info:
          NOT AVAILABLE

          NOT AVAILABLE

        running dist_info
        running build_src
        build_src
        building py_modules sources
        creating build
        creating build\src.win32-3.6
        creating build\src.win32-3.6\numpy
        creating build\src.win32-3.6\numpy\distutils
        building library "npymath" sources
        Running from numpy source directory.
        setup.py:461: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and
expanding templates
          run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
        C:\Users\flegg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-ydesvn0r\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1896: UserWarnin
g:
            Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
            Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
            A better performance should be easily gained by switching
            Blas library.
          if self._calc_info(blas):
        C:\Users\flegg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-ydesvn0r\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1896: UserWarnin
g:
            Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
            Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
            the BLAS environment variable.
          if self._calc_info(blas):
        C:\Users\flegg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-ydesvn0r\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1896: UserWarnin
g:
            Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
            Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
            the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
          if self._calc_info(blas):
        C:\Users\flegg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-ydesvn0r\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1730: UserWarnin
g:
            Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
            Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
            the LAPACK environment variable.
          return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
        C:\Users\flegg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-ydesvn0r\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1730: UserWarnin
g:
            Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
            Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
            numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
            the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
          return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
        C:\Users\flegg\Pypy\pypy-c-jit-98354-1608da62bfc7-win32\lib-python\3\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: U
nknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
          warnings.warn(msg)
        error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.1 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visuals
tudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
        ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\flegg\pypy venv\bin\pypy.exe' 'c:\users\flegg\pypy ve
nv\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\flegg\AppData\Local
\Temp\tmp_z50eost' Check the logs for full command output.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\flegg\pypy venv\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 128, in fetch_build_egg
        subprocess.check_call(cmd)
      File "C:\Users\flegg\Pypy\pypy-c-jit-98354-1608da62bfc7-win32\lib-python\3\subprocess.py", line 311, in chec
k_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['c:\\users\\flegg\\pypy venv\\bin\\pypy.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable
-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\flegg\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpg6tpv8wp', '--quiet',
 'numpy>=1.13.3']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\flegg\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kv0nhuc2\pandas\setup.py", line 840, in <module>
        **setuptools_kwargs
      File "c:\users\flegg\pypy venv\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "c:\users\flegg\pypy venv\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 139, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "c:\users\flegg\pypy venv\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 721, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "c:\users\flegg\pypy venv\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 782, in resolve
        replace_conflicting=replace_conflicting
      File "c:\users\flegg\pypy venv\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1065, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "c:\users\flegg\pypy venv\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1077, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "c:\users\flegg\pypy venv\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 777, in fetch_build_egg
        return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
      File "c:\users\flegg\pypy venv\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 130, in fetch_build_egg
        raise DistutilsError(str(e))
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['c:\\users\\flegg\\pypy venv\\bin\\pypy.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disab
le-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\flegg\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpg6tpv8wp', '--quiet
', 'numpy>=1.13.3']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: You’re using Venv, right?

Comment: yes, i am. I have both a conda environment and a pypy one. This error is only on the pypy environment.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that pandas wants numpy, numpy installation is failing to find your compiler: `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.1 is required.`.

You might want to update setuptools (the module that looks for the compiler) via `pip install --upgrade setuptools`. Hopefully you are using the [latest PyPy 7.3 release](https://www.pypy.org/download.html)